How to rectify this authentication problem
I am creating a login page for my new project. When logging in, the password can't match. It says Invalid password. This is my code.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-14">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ceylon-cuisine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap-5.3.3-dist/bootstrap-5.3.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ceylon-cuisine.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:ital,wght@0,100..700;1,100..700&family=Satisfy&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap">
  <script src="ceylon-cuisine.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST["login"])){

        $email = $_POST['email_address'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        require_once "dbconn.php";

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_address = '$email'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if($user) {

            if(password_verify($password, $user["password"])) {

                header("Location: recipes.php");
                die();

            } else {

                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid password</div>";

            }

        } else {

            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>User not found</div>";
        }
    }

?>


                


  <script src="./bootstrap-5.3.3-dist/bootstrap-5.3.3-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <header class="text-white align-items-center fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-3 d-flex align-items-center">
          <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo-img img-fluid rounded-circle">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <h1 class="display-4 m-0 josefin-sans mt-2">Ceylon Cuisine</h1>
          <p class="tagline text-center">Experience the Taste of Tradition</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 text-end">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-5">
                <li class="nav-item ubuntu-light-italic">
                  <a href="homePage.php" class="nav-link" target="_top">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ubuntu-light-italic">
                  <a href="aboutus.php" class="nav-link" target="_top">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ubuntu-light-italic">
                  <a href="contacts.php" class="nav-link" target="_top">Contacts</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="#" class="nav-link ubuntu-light-italic">Recipes</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container rounded-3 col-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center mt-5 mb-5 vh-100" id="welcome">
  <form method="post">
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email_address">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
  </form>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div class="container-fluid justify-content-center align-items-center mt-1">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="">
              <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
              <a href="#">Terms of Conditions</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="mt-2">
                <p>&copy; ceylon-cuisine 2024</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>

I am expecting to correct mistakes in my code or find alternative for this process. Feel free to go through my code and address the problem. The bug is related to how passwords are verified in the database. The password is stored in a hashed format, and I am using password_verify() to verify the entered password against the hashed password.

Warning: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the mysqli documentation and this: How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP? . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

In terms of your actual issue: we can't see how you hashed and stored the password, or where you stored it. Nor did you provide any test data (i.e. the value stored in the database's password field, or the raw password you're using as input) in order for us to work out what might be happening.

Assuming you are indeed storing hashed passwords in the database, the most common reason for this problem is that you used a database field of less than 60 characters to store the hash. You can prevent this mistake from occurring by reading the documentation carefully before creating the password field in the database.

P.S. Another security problem: If either the username or password is incorrect, you should simply output "credentials invalid" (or something similar). Do not tell the user whether it was the username or the password which was incorrect. This gives hackers unnecessary clues - e.g. if they manage to get the username correctly, and you indicate to them that only the password is wrong, all they have to do then is try to crack the password, which is a lot less work for them than if they're unsure whether the username or the password was wrong.

Warning: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. It is not generally a suitable topic for an inexperienced or beginner programmer. Any modern development framework like Laravel comes with an authentication system built-in. I recommend focusing your time on learning PHP and adding genuine value to your application with new features, not something you can re-use a (reliable, well-made) product for.
